# If (flat) earth were accelerating at $9.8m/s^2$ how long would it take to reach the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, speed-of-light, acceleration

I am having (numerous) debates with flat earthers. Futile, I know. But it's entertaining all the same.

If you didn't know a lot of them deny the existence of gravity, and when pushed they come up with with various theories: all of which are nonsense, and some of which require gravity to work.

One of the theories is that the flat earth is moving upwards at a speed of 9.8m/s. Obviously this is ridiculous but it occurred to me that if this were maintained then eventually earth would accelerate past the speed of light. A physical impossibility.

Assuming earth started accelerating today at that constant, how long would it take to reach the speed of light?

Comment: This seems to be off topic here. See this [site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4539/7433).

Comment: Migrate to [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) perhaps ?

Comment: Nothing can reach the speed of light. You could ask this question: us om Earth don't observe that upwards acceleration. So who do? Who can tell us that we accelerate upwards? Who are we comparing to?

Comment: You could instead ask them why we haven't run into the sun or moon yet, since they hover above earth in the same direction we're accelerating and are actually quite close to the plane of the planet.

Answer (score 5):

A flat earth accelerating with a constant acceleration will never reach the speed of light. It requires an infinite energy for a massive object to reach this speed. As the energy added by acceleration is always finite, the earth will be forever approaching the speed of light, but bever reach it. Sorry, but it looks like you just lost an argument with the flat earthers ;)

Comment: I am aware of this. I was wondering if at this rate of acceleration whether the earth would have ALREADY (based on its current age)  reached that point and thus gravity would simply cease to exist as the acceleration could no longer continue.

Comment: This answer could be improved by actually showing the relevant equation for relativistic acceleration, making it clear exactly how the velocity asymptotically approaches the speed of light. If you show the flat-earther how relativistic velocities are reached within roughly a year, thus making any interstellar clouds and other stuff deadly, you might bbe able to convince the flat-earthed that… no wait, you will never be able to convince them anyway…

Comment: @macker : reached *what* point?  There *is* no point when you reach the speed of light

Comment: @Macker to put it another way: no matter how close you get to the speed of light, I can always boost to a reference frame where the flat earth is stationary (only at the initial instance of time, of course) and accelerating, meaning that there's no special point on the trajectory. The acceleration is smooth and eternal. However, this picture is purely theoretical and doesn't take into account many relevant factors like CMB, for example. In the real Universe the blue-shifted CMB will eventually reach Planckian energies where new physics is expected to emerge.

Comment: @Solenodon Paradoxus: I think at the Plank energies it's much more likely for the physics to end than to emerge :) Luckily we'll never know, as one would need to convert 2000 galaxies of the Virgo cluster with quadrillions of stars to energy of a single particle to get it there.

Comment: @safesphere not really, no. If we could transform the rest energy of a dust particle into a single photon it would become Planckian.

Comment: @Solenodon Paradoxus: Perhaps. I actually was referring to the energy needed for a proton in the LHC to resolve the details on the Plank scale of length.

Comment: @safesphere well ok then. But is still think that the CMB is the key factor for any real-life uniform acceleration scenario.

Comment: If you could keep accelerating at 9.8m/s/s, you would reach the speed of light. But you can't.

Answer (score 3):

In General Relativity, an object can experience a constant proper acceleration forever and never exceed the speed of light in the frame of an inertial observer.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration).

That being said, if you're talking to somebody who believes that the Earth is flat, presumably General Relativity is out the window, so it's a bit of a pointless exercise in futility.

Comment: General Relativity is out the window when it supports a spherical Earth. It is perfectly fine to use General Relativity when it supports a flat Earth. This is what happens when a conspiratorial mindset takes over (and it would take a vast conspiracy to hide a flat Earth).

Answer (score 1):

The Godwhale equation (from the book *The Godwhale*  by T.J. Bass) makes the point   that $gy=c$. In other words that if we accelerate at $g= 9.81$  ms$^{-2}$ for one year, we reach the speed of light.  Of course this uses non-relativistic kinematics, and is probably a numerical coincidence, but  it is a dimensionally correct equation (true in any units) accurate to a few percent and  rather striking.